# Doubt on immediate attribute for command button

Tags: jsf

HI,

I have a doubt on setting the immediate attribute for the command button. I would like to know what will be the changes in the life cycle?

I have read that setting immediate attribute will call the action listener or action methods in the apply request values phase. My doubts is it only the difference of preponding the phase. Also it will execute the all the business logic in the action methods regardless of setting the immediate attribute.

Please clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `immediate="true"` is set in an `UICommand` component, then the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) in the same `UIForm`. Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.

If `immediate="true"` is set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components in the same `UIForm`, then the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) in the same form which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.

#### See also

- [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Comment: But, It is confusing. If we set UIInput as true, then it is not sipping the phases when UICommand also set as true. Am I correct? In that case if we want to use validations for few fields in the form, then set their immediate attribute as true and set command as true. correct?

Comment: If `immediate="true"` is set in an `UIInput` component only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, then the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Now I am clear with few points. But, I have already create another questions with few questions. Please answer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746885/immediate-attribute-for-uiinput-component

Comment: You're welcome. In the future you could also just create a test form and play around it yourself.

Comment: Yes. I am creating and doing myself learning to understand the concepts. Its very interesting.