# Immediate attribute for UIInput component

Tags: jsf

HI,

If I am adding the immediate attribute true for the UIInput component and UICommand button doesn't have the immediate attribute. What will be the flow? Please answer my below questions.

- If that UIInput has the invalid data, will the error shown in the screen.
- If there is another UIInput component with immediate attribute, if this also has the invalid data, will the error shown in the screen.
- I know that the validation will happen in the Apply Request values phase. Does the only validation happens or conversion also happens.

Please clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If that UIInput has the invalid data, will the error shown in the screen.

Yes.

> If there is another UIInput component with immediate attribute, if this also has the invalid data, will the error shown in the screen.

Yes.

> I know that the validation will happen in the Apply Request values phase. Does the only validation happens or conversion also happens.

Conversion happens always directly before validation in the same phase.