# jsf inputtext not updating value after changing it in bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

The short version of my problem is that the inputtext will not change the value in bean after I modified the value from the bean.
The longer version:
There is a form in which is a dataTable with user information; some inputTexts, and two buttons. If you fill the inputTexts, a new user will be created with the given data, and appears in dataTable - this works fine, I can create as many users as I can.
The tricky part is if you select a row from the dataGrid, the user information has to appear in the inputText fields - this works fine - so the admin can modify them. But after changing the inputText values in the bean, if the admin changes someting in the inputText, the value "will not follow" tha changes, the value remains the same. What could I do wrong?
The JSF page looks like this:

```html
<html>
<h:body>
  <h:form style="font-size:14px;" id="setupform">
    ...
      <p:panel header="Edit users" id="userAddingPanel" rendered="#{settingsbean.validLogin}">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="userAddingGrid">
          <p:outputLabel value="User Name: " />
          <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{settingsbean.userName}" />

          <p:outputLabel value="User Password: " />
          <p:password id="userPass" value="#{settingsbean.userPassword}" />

          <p:outputLabel value="E-mail address: " />
          <p:inputText id="userMailAddress" value="#{settingsbean.mailAddress}" />

          <p:outputLabel id="userDelete" value="Inactivate User: " />
          <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isUserDeleted" value="#{settingsbean.deletedUser}" />

          <p:commandButton id="addUser" value="Create User" update="userAddingGrid" icon="ui-icon-disk" action="#{settingsbean.addNewUser}" />

          <p:commandButton id="modifyUser" value="Modify User" icon="ui-icon-wrench" update="userAddingGrid" action="#{settingsbean.updateUser}" process="setupform"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <br/>

        <p:dataTable id="usersTable" var="users" value="#{settingsbean.userList}" tableStyle="overflow: auto;" stickyHeader="true" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{users.id}" selection="#{settingsbean.selectedUser}">

          <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":setupform:userName, :setupform:userName,
                :setupform:userPass, :setupform:userMailAddress, :setupform:isUserDeleted" />

          <p:column headerText="#ID">
            <h:outputText value="#{users.id}" />
          </p:column>

          <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{users.loginName}" />
          </p:column>
          ...
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

And my bean looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name ="settingsbean")
@ViewScoped
public class SettingsBean {
private String userName;
private String userPassword;
private boolean deletedUser;
private List<UserDTO> userList;
private UserDTO selectedUser;
/*with getters and setters, what is uncenventional is this setter*/
public void setSelectedUser(UserDTO selectedUser) {
/*if admin selects/unselects a user from dataTable*/        
this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
/*if unselect user*/
        if(selectedUser == null){
            userName = "";
            mailAddress = "";
            deletedUser = false;
/*if selects user*/        
}else {
            userName = selectedUser.getLoginName();
            mailAddress = selectedUser.getMailAddress();
            deletedUser = selectedUser.getDeleted();
        }
    }
...
public void addNewUser(){ 
//creates a new user in DB
}

public void updateUser(){
//will update user in DB
}
}
```

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed! (If you would have created a [mcve] you'd have found that it at least plays a role in your problem) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665524/form-within-form-skip-validation-of-parent-form

Comment: Tankk you for pointing that. I removed the inner form, the HTML contains only one form by now.

Comment: I would like to emphasis that Nested forms are not allowed as stated by Kukeltje. If you are using templates check that you have one form either in your parent template or current page. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to process the components that you want to be updated

```
<p:commandButton id="modifyUser" value="Modify User" icon="ui-icon-wrench" update="userAddingGrid" action="#{settingsbean.updateUser}" process="userAddingGrid"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems, that it did not help. I tried to process the form also, but in vain.

Comment: That's rare. where are you verifying that the values were updated? if you are doing it in the database maybe the problem is in your update method, are you sure yo are reassigning  the userName, mailAddress and deletedUser to your selectedUser DTO before you use it in the update method?

Comment: I just debugged it. I _stopped_ the function what the "Create User" calls, right at the first row, and evaluated the userName, userPassword,... fields, so I see is before DB, or any other function calls. It looks like the field setter methods unhook, or will not call, just after reloading the whole page.

Comment: bind your inputs to a UIComponent and get the data directly from the component

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but unfortunatelly it did not help. :/ I changed the value to bingind, but in the code I got the same result. I also tried it with a different browser, but in vain. Later I tought it has to do something with the bean scope, so I changed it to SessionScope, but with the same result.