# Update Action in Bean for JSF

Tags: jsf

Although it is a simple question . Need an answer for this.
I have written a jsp page as :

```
<body>
<f:view>
    <f:loadBundle basename="message" var="msg"/>
<h:form id="edit">

    <h:panelGroup>      
        <h:selectOneRadio id="CompletePublication" layout="pageDirection">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="SUCCESS" itemValue="true"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="FAILED" itemValue="false"/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>                         
     </h:panelGroup>
        <h:commandButton id="setAction" immediate="true" action="#{user.completePublication}" value="#{msg.Button_OK}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="cancel" immediate="true" action="#{user.cancelCompletePublish}" value="#{msg.Button_CANCEL}"/>
</h:form>
</f:view>               
</body>
```

It needs to be handled under theBean:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private boolean action;

    public boolean getAction()
    {
        System.out.println("Get");
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(boolean action)
    {
        this.action=action;
        System.out.println("Set");
    }
    public String completePublication(){
        if (action==true){
            System.out.println("Value of True Action - " + action);
            return "updated";
        }
        if (action==false){
            System.out.println("Value of False Action - " + action);
            return "notupdated";
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String cancelCompletePublish()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        return null;
    }

}
```

So can any one help on this. At the output evertime i see the "Value of False Action - False"

Comment: Go through: http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUIInputOnly

Comment: Look here what [`immediate=true`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735085/1199132) means and how is affecting to your form.

Comment: I know it looks basic but for making this code work will give me better insight. So if possible for you all to make the changes and let em know the O/P

Answer (score 1):

In your `<h:selectOneRadio>` you are not passing the value of the selected choice back to your bean when the form is submitted. Therefore, the `action` variable will never get updated. Assuming that you refer to your managed bean as `user` in the page, you will need to modify that component by adding the `value` attribute. Therefore, change

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="CompletePublication" layout="pageDirection">
```

to

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="CompletePublication" value="#{user.action}" layout="pageDirection">
```

For more information on `<h:selectOneRadio>` please refer to [this link](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html). Also, as mentioned by @Xtreme Biker, you need to understand what `immediate="true"` does when it is applied to a particular component. For ***your*** case, when a user hits any of the `<h:commandButton>`, the Update Model Phase (as well as other phases) will be skipped. In other words, `action` will never be set to `true` when the user selects `SUCCESS` and then clicks the `OK` (first) button. That's why you always see `Value of False Action - False` in your output. To fix this just remove the `immediate` attribute in the first `<h:commandButton>` like so

```
<h:commandButton id="setAction" action="#{user.completePublication}" value="#{msg.Button_OK}"/>
```

After removing that attribute, make the following change in your `completePublication` method

```
public String completePublication(){
    if (action){
        System.out.println("Value of True Action - " + action);
        return "updated";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Value of False Action - " + action);
        return "notupdated";
    }
}
```

There is no need to return `null` since `action` will either be `true` or `false`.

**NOTE** I intentionally did not go into detail on the behavior of the `immediate` attribute. If you want to understand it, you will need to spend some time to try and understand the JSF lifecycle phases. In fact, you will need to be somewhat comfortable with these concepts as you dive deeper into JSF. Both @johny and @Xtreme Biker gave you some good links to start with. I am copying them below just in case their comments get erased.

[Debug JSF Lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

[Doubt on immediate attribute for command button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731740/doubt-on-immediate-attribute-for-command-button/4735085#4735085)